# Changes to Web Service not reflected in application that has Web Reference

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webforms

I am required to learn asp.net web services with web forms. I have a web form project that has a web service added as a Web Reference. The problem is, whenever I change anything about the web service (add new methods/services for example), it is not reflected in the application that has the web reference and tells me the new method doesn't exist. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to right-click the web reference and click **Update Web Reference** to update it manually when the web service contract changes.

Visual Studio will then re-download the [wsdl](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) from the service and use it to re-generate the service proxy classes in the client.

**Note**
Check that you rebuild your web service first, and that those changes are available on the URL used by the web reference in the client project (i.e. if the client app is referencing `http://server.mydomain.local/services/CI/myservice/myservice.asmx` then just re-building locally won't be enough, you'll need to either deploy the webservice changes or point your client to `localhost` before you update the web reference.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have to re-import the reference to the webservice. I doubt this definition constantly gets updated like it's a class in your project.

Comment: You don't have to re-import, you can update. See my answer for details.

Comment: This is it. Go to the Web Reference in your Solution Explorer, right click and select "Update Web Reference".

Comment: I am sure I did click update on the web reference and it didn't work. I will try again.

Comment: You're right about the update function. Totally slipped my mind. Still, doesn't update automatically. Sounds stupid at first, but is kind of logical, since you don't really know where the webservice is, or if it's available at all.